# Yii framework scalability

Tags: php, yii

I'm a starter in yii framework. I just want know how scalable Yii is with a lot of online users at a time?

How useful is Yii in comparison to other frameworks and also if there are 100,000 users - to have things move smoothly - what kind of technology and hosting etc would be needed?

Comment: I also want to know.. i think the title should not compatibility.

Comment: Hi, here is another question about Yii framework usage, comparison with other frameworks etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741274/experience-using-yii-framework-for-actual-php-project/

Comment: I built, in Yii, the number search system for a certain state's lottery numbers (yes like powerball and junk). This site receives well over a million hits per day. No performance issues whatsoever from Yii. What we found is that the servers were the bottleneck. Apache could handle, at the most, around 500 requests per second. We ended up deploying total of six web servers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article compares Yii and Drupal on a website with more than 50000 visitors per day. http://erickennedy.org/Drupal-7-Reasons-to-Switch

Answer (score 2):

100,000 users is a bit vague. Is that per minute, per hour or day? Yii does have a good caching functionality but perhaps worth reading *Building Scalable Web Sites: Building, Scaling, and Optimizing the Next Generation of Web Applications* by Cal Henderson, as this will give a better understand of scaling PHP web applications.